# Does Firefox on Linux support viewing source code in an external viewer?

Tags: linux, firefox

I am using Firefox 102.6.0esr (64-Bit) on Linux. I have added these lines to about:config

```
view_source.editor.external true
view_source.editor.path "/usr/bin/xed"
```

but I can't get to open the source of any page in xed (text editor).

Does Firefox even support this feature?

Answer (score 1):

The path is incorrect.

- When I set the path to `"/usr/bin/geany"`, right-click on a page and select **View Page Source**, FFox opens the source in a new tab with `view-source:<URL>` as the address
- When I set the path to `/usr/bin/geany`, right-click on a page and select **View Page Source**, FFox opens the source in geany

Comment: Thanks. With your suggestion I can see the whole page source, However not a selection of it.

Comment: That's not what you asked either...

Comment: According to [Mozilla documentation](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/view_source/index.html) `If you select part of a web page and context-click, you’ll see a context menu item labeled “View Selection Source”, that behaves just like “View Page Source”, except you only see the source for the selection.` - i.e. it will also open up in the external editor.

Comment: Quick testing with FFox 102.7.0esr - yes, it does. "View Selection Source" also generally opens the external editor, but this isn't as straight-forward as viewing page source. It's clearly related to how I choose on the page - for example my choice hits between <div></div>, it seems to open the entire element; but if my choice extends to the next <div>, the source still may open in a tab instead of my editor.

Comment: I might have worded my question better. And I though the functionality didn't even exist. In either cases, on my Laptop running Debian, it still won't open any selection in xed.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be consistent either. For example in the Moz doc link choosing the text **Limitations of View Source**, right-clicking and choosing "View Selection Source" previously opened that element in geany. Now, without me changing the setup, it opens in a tab... "View Page Source" opens on geany...